# Complex ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am a bit stuck with my Ajax Filtering DropDown selection.

I have below selections and options:

**Selection1**
 *Option1: Male
Option2: Female*

**Selection2**
*Option1: Guess
Option2: H&M*

**Selection3**
*Option1: Watch (Guess,H&M)
Option2: Shirt (Guess,H&M)
Option3: Bikini (Guess,H&M)(only if Selection1 is Female)
Option4: Accessories (H&M)*

My problem is how to filter `Selection3` when user select `Female` which will include `Option3` in `selection3` which is `Bikini`, while `Selection 2` will also filter `Selection 3` base on the brand.

Comment: You probably gonna need to specify your problem a little more and add some code of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a listener for [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) on the selects

so for example:

```
jQuery('.select1').on('change',function(){
    $this = jQuery(this);
    if($this.val() === 2){ // 2 == female
       jQuery('.select3 option[value="4"]').show();
    }else{
       jQuery('.select3 option[value="4"]').hide();
    }
});
```

(this requires you to have it as value 4 (you can also change my item names ofc. select1, select3 etc.)